# Is there a way to get the event queue in Vert.x?

Tags: java, vert.x

"I am learning about Vert.x and trying to find a way to get the event queue in Vert.x, but I cannot find any documentation or instructions on how to do this. I am wondering if I misunderstood that Vert.x does not have an event queue or if it's located in Netty."

Comment: why do you need the event queue at all? You are going down the wrong path